# How to enforce processing only one task per executor in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark to process my data. My Spark job is **Map-only** operation and I am using some external library to process my data. This external library has a memory leak bug. When the executor starts, it processes couple of files/partitions successfully but because of this memory bug, it starts failing.

I have hard dependency on this external library and the memory leak bug won't be fixed soon. So, I am looking for alternative options to run my spark job (at the cost of low performance)

As I mentioned earlier, the each executor can easily process couple of files/partitions, I think, if I can configure my Spark application to use one executor per task i.e. kill the executor after processing the assigned task and create new executor for next task, I might be able to run my job.

*I want to know, if there is a way to configure Spark to create new executor for each available task?*

I have already tried using `spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=0` but this does not create new executor for each task.

Comment: are you looking to have one executor/node and in that one executor you want to run 1 task? for example if you've 10 nodes cluster then you'll be able to run 1 Executor/Node (can give whole memory on node to that Executor) and 1 task/Executor so in this case you can have 10 Executors (which will run only 10 tasks) in cluster for that application. I can provide solution if that's what you're looking for

Comment: No, I am looking for one executor per task/partition.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set `spark.executor.cores=1`, like this there will be only 1 task (at a time) for each executor jvm. But still, there will be several tasks per executor which run sequentially

Comment: A thin answer, if at all, Raphael.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible and would not make sense architecturally.

Design is made assuming things will work, not that there will be issues. There is no mention of this capability in the manuals.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are other ways to workaround the problem (besides fixing the library)?

How does it exactly leak? If it, say, leaks memory inside a library object you could try to allocate a library object per partition:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(iter => {
  val lib = new MyLibrary()
  iter.map(elem => lib.doSomething(elem))
})
```

If it creates a leak in some static global variable then you could try to load create a new classloader per partition and load a the library using this classloader.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The memory leak is while transforming data and not with class loader. Hence as each executor process more data, it fails eventually. That is why, I was looking for option to create new executor for each partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `spark.task.cpus=n` to enforce **n** cores to execute one task.

When **n** = cores in executor, each executor can run 1 task.